# How to delete an obj in queue during BFS (C++)?

Tags: c++, linked-list, tree, breadth-first-search

I am writing a program that contains BFS in it. It will do BFS on a tree in which each node contains some attributes. I used the linked list to represent the tree.  My code is huge and I cannot post it here. This is a summary of what I do:

During BFS I use a queue of the node types.

```
queue <TreeNodes*> my_queue;
```

And as in the usual BFS, I push and pop nodes in the queue. During the BFS I need to update the tree, means I might delete some nodes and update the tree.

During the BFS I occur segmentation fault, and I know its reason but not sure how to address it.

Assume during BFS I pushed node "x" into the queue. Then in the next iterations while I am poping out node "y" I might delete node "x", while it is still in the queue. This makes an issue once I pop out "x".

Initially, I thought if I delete this node by a pointer in the tree, it would automatically delete it from queue too. But seems once I push a node into the queue, it pushes a copy of it. I am not sure how I can actually delete it from the queue, or at least once I delete it from the tree make it null. Becuase it is not actually null and points to nowhere and has some random numbers as its attributes in it.

I did not know that what I should search so I asked it here.

Comment: Your problem is with your choice of data structures. yes, a queue is dynamite for breadth traversals, but the very point of a queue is things only go in one way and out the other. No internal node access is typically allowed (or required, since you already know it's a queue and wouldn't be using it if you needed something else).

Comment: @WhozCraig You are right. Now my question is that does it add a copy of the node to the queue? Or it pushes the address of the node? (I added my queue in the question)

Comment: @Sarah: The question shows a queue of pointers, so that would hold pointers (addresses). However, destroying what it points at leaves a stale pointer, so attempting to dereference that  pointer gives undefined behavior--quite possibly including getting the values in the deleted object (e.g., if that memory hasn't been used for anything else yet).

Comment: @JerryCoffin that`s true, I got some random values, Do you know any solution to avoid it?

Answer (score 2):

One possibility would be to use `shared_ptr`s in the tree, and `weak_ptr`s in the queue. Using them is somewhat non-trivial, but the basic idea is that the `shared_ptr` has ownership of what it points at, and a `weak_ptr` gives the ability to observe the same things--but if the `shared_ptr` disposes of the object, the `weak_ptr` will let you know that what you're trying to look at has disappeared rather than attempting to use a pointer that's now stale.